# Does there exist a set $Y$ such that $Y \cong \Sigma^Y$ for a fixed set $\Sigma$?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, category-theory

Suppose $\Sigma$ is a set.  I'm wondering if there exists a set $Y$ such that $Y \cong \Sigma^Y$?  Can this set be constructed as some kind of limit in **Set**?  In which kinds of categories is such a construction possible?  If the answer to any of the above is yes, is there somewhere I can read more about this?

Comment: If $\Sigma$ contains at least two elements, then $\left|\Sigma^Y\right|\geqslant\left|2^Y\right|>|Y|$ for any set $Y$. Consequently, if $\Sigma$ contains at least two elements, it does not exist any set $Y$ such that $Y\cong\Sigma^Y$.

Comment: Thanks @Angelo! That is a quick argument.

Comment: It's not unusual to have $\text{Hom} (\Sigma, Y) \cong Y$ in some category (for example $\Sigma = \{1\}$ in the category of sets or $\Sigma = k$ in the category of $k$-vector spaces). So take the opposite of such a category.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Lawvere's fixed point theorem](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Lawvere%27s+fixed+point+theorem) states that given a surjection $f : Y \to \Sigma^Y$, every function $g : \Sigma \to \Sigma$ has a fixed point. For (classical) sets the only set with this property that every endofunction has a fixed point is the singleton set. Any larger set has a function that swaps two elements and the empty set has no points, so functions on it can't have fixed points.

In this case, if $\Sigma \cong 1$ then $\Sigma^Y \cong 1$, so $Y \cong \Sigma^Y$ is true precisely when $Y \cong 1$ too.

Comment: Ah okay, this definitely makes sense.  Is there a category in which there are non-trivial object $\Sigma$ with this property? (Also, thank you for the link, this article is very interesting!)

Comment: @AndrewStocker I don't know of any simple examples offhand, but you might be interested in [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/131173/lawveres-fixed-point-theorem-and-the-recursion-theorem) or [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/139645/applications-of-lawveres-fixed-point-theorem) on mathoverflow.

Comment: Thanks so much!